# How to check if MongoDB connection is established with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

In my app, MongoDB 3.2.4 runs on a custom port, I want to implement logic where my app will try to reach MongoDB on a custom port and if it fails it will use the default `27018` port.

In order to do that I use the following code:

```java
String mongoClientURI = "mongodb://" + DB_SRV_USR + ":" + DB_SRV_PWD + "@" + DB_URL + ":" + DB_PORT_CUS + "/" + dbName;
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(mongoClientURI);

// enable SSL connection
MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).build();

if (this.mongoClient == null) {
    this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
}

// create database if doesn't exist
MongoDatabase mdb = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);

try {
    this.mongoClient.getAddress();
} catch (com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException e) {
    System.out.println("Switch to default port");
    /*…use default port logic…*/
}
```

The problem is that this exception is not caught.
Although MongoDB throws the following exception:

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
> com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)    at
> com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
> at
> com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)   at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
> at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
> com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
> at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
> ... 3 more

my `try-catch` expression can't catch this exception.

I tried multiple approaches, such as to catch:

- `Exception`
- `RuntimeException`
- `MongoSocketOpenException`
- `MongoException`
- `MongoCommandException`

none of them doesn't work.

My questions:

1. How can I check if MongoDB connection is established?
2. How can catch the exception `MongoSocketOpenException`?

Comment: I agree with Frankenapps, that sentence is not throwing the exception. I think that it is being thrown when you instantiate your client. Catch the exception there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I use this code to check connection:

   ```
   try {
       mongo.getAddress();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Database unavailable!");
       mongo.close();
       return;
   }
   ```
2. Not sure here my guess would be that `this.mongoClient.getAddress();` does not throw that exception, but I don't really know

EDIT: I initialized it via:

```
Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(3000);  
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("192.168.0.1", 3000), builder.build());
```

Comment: What type `mongo` object is? In my case `mongoClient` is a type of `MongoClient`.

Comment: It looks like we use the same object but different constructor. I use:
`String mongoClientURI = "mongodb://" + DB_SRV_USR + ":" + DB_SRV_PWD + "@" + DB_URL + ":" + DB_PORT_CUS + "/" + dbName;
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(mongoClientURI);
// enable SSL connection
MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).build();`

Comment: I just tried your approach and the exception was not caught as well.

Comment: Is there a better way ?